# CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToCFHost CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost and allocations

Tags: ios, sockets, memory-management

Can some one please give me the difference between `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToCFHost` and `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost` calls.

Also what is a `CFAllocator` and what is the meaning if that is `NULL` or `kCFAllocatorDefault`. Since its a `kCFAllocatorDefault` is a const can someone explain the beleifits of `kCFAllocatorDefault` or is it the for historical purposes only?

Comment: I think that documentation is your friend...

Answer (score 3):

The difference between `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToCFHost` and `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost` is simply the way the address is passed in.

In `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost`, you can simply define a `CFStringRef` (or `NSString`) to represent the domain / ip of the host.

With the `CFHost` version, however, it gives you control over the address via the `sockaddr_in` struct, defined in `<netinet/in.h>`. You create a `CFHostRef` in a manner similar to the following:

```
struct sockaddr_in ip4addr; // note that this only works for ipv4, for ipv6 you need struct sockaddr_in6.

ip4addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
ip4addr.sin_port = htons(3490);
inet_pton(AF_INET, "10.0.0.1", &ip4addr.sin_addr);

CFDataRef sockData = CFDataCreate(NULL, &ip4addr, sizeof(ip4addr));
CFHostRef host = CFHostCreateWithAddress(NULL, sockData);
// use 'host' to create your stream   

CFRelease(host);
CFRelease(sockData);
```

This gives you some (mostly unnecessary) control over what you do with the socket itself, for most situations, the `CFHost` version is not necessary.

For `CFAllocator`'s, once again, the documentation is your friend. It is used as `CoreFoundation`'s way for debugging `malloc`, `free`, and `realloc` calls throughout the code.

It is an object that allows you to write your own methods for allocating memory for an object, and `kCFAllocatorDefault` uses the standard `malloc`, `free`, and `realloc` calls used by the system. Passing `NULL` for a `CFAllocator` works exactly the same as `kCFAllocatorDefault`, the code just uses the system calls.